# Here API Autosuggest - request address only

Tags: here-api

Is there a way in the autosuggest endpoint to request only addresses?  (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html)

It looks like the Autocomplete api (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html) returns only addresses, but I am not sure if the "in maintenance" means it will be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the services IN MAINTENANCE
also ,it simply means the service is no longer being actively developed. We will only provide critical fixes for this service in future.